# Im having trouble getting this PHP form to to capture and forward to email

Tags: php, forms, email

The form is for a charity event website, and im really having trouble getting the PHP to take the info from the form and send it to the email we needed. Im not much of a web designer (this is made in bootstrap), but I assume the problem is in the PHP. Thanks for the help!

```
    <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="contactform" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="shift">Preferred Shift</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <select class="form-control" id="shift" name="shift">
            <option value="1" required> Shift 1: 12pm - 3:30pm </option>
            <option value="2" required> Shift 2: 3:30pm - 7pm </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="shirt">Shirt Size</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <select class="form-control" id="shirt" name="shirt">
            <option value="1" required> XS </option>
            <option value="2" required> S </option>
            <option value="3" required> M </option>
            <option value="4" required> L </option>
            <option value="5" required> XL </option>
            <option value="6" required> XXL </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comments">Comments </label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <textarea class="form-control" type="text" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comments Not Required"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-6">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit"> Submit </button>
          <br>
          <h5> *all volunteers must be 18 years or older </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I have the PHP included in the same site. It looks like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "info@charitycelebration.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $shift = $_POST['shift'];
    $shirt = $_POST['shirt'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $subject = "CC volunteer submission";

    $message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

    $message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";

    $message .= "Email: ".clean_string($from)."\n";

    $message .= "Shift: ".clean_string($shift)."\n";

    $message .= "Shirt: ".clean_string($shirt)."\n";

    $message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


    mail($to,$subject,$message);
    echo "==[]-]0ploi9ok.,/,Thank you " . $name . ", we will see you soon!";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

Comment: What "trouble" are you having? Any error? One possibility: the form does not have any action attribute.

Comment: Basic debugging which you should have done first: Confirm that your form is submitting properly (`var_dump($_POST)`), check the return value of `mail()` (it returns boolean `false` on failure), check your mail server's logs to see what happened if/when php handed over the email.

Comment: Im not getting any errors. After clicking submit, the page refreshes but no email is sent or received. I have absolutely no experience with PHP, that entire section is put together from examples online

Answer (score 1):

mail() is highly dependent on having your mail set up correctly on the server.  Personally I like the additional control of the PEAR Mail_mime package, but that is overkill for your usage if you can get basic mail functionality up and running

Focus on getting a basic mail message sent first - no variables or other elements, then once successful go back and insert your form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `echo` the variables `$to, $subject, $message` instead of calling `mail()`, to see if all input to `mail()` has came correctly from the form and the `clean_string()` functions you use. If input to `mail()` is correct, then there is probably a problem with `mail()`.